# hold time and talk time with twilio

Tags: ruby, api, ruby-on-rails-3.2, twilio

I am using twilio in my rails 3.2 application.

I am forwarding inbound calls with Dial verb, 
I need to determine:

1) The total hold time

2) The total talk time

of a particular call for billing purpose.

Is it possible with twilio?

Comment: Twilio evangelist here.  A clarifying question, how are you placing your callers on "hold"?

Comment: @DevinRader, I dont place a caller on hold, when a caller calls on twilio number, I forward the call to another non-twilio number with Dial verb.

Comment: OK and after dialing the non-Twilio number they call can be put on hold?

Comment: @DevinRader, Yes after dialing the non-Twilio number, the call can be put on hold by the owner of the non-twilio number(call-center).

Comment: Then there is really no way for Twilio to know whats going on in the call once we've dialed the second number.  We can tell you how long that call was connected, but we don't have any way of knowing specifically whats happened while connected.  Hope that helps.

Comment: no problem.  added my comment as an actual answer for future readers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Twilio evangelist here.

Then there is really no way for Twilio to know whats going on in the call once we've dialed the second number. We can tell you how long that call was connected via [`duration`](https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/rest/call#instance-properties), but we don't have any way of knowing specifically whats happened while connected.

Hope that helps.